# Use only css to add a hyperlink text

Tags: html, forms, css

I wanted to display a hyperlink just after every text box only using css. Is there any methods? I am in a serious problem. Please help.

Comment: No, this isn't possible. You could only try and 'fake' it by using pseudo selectors like `:after`

Comment: thank you. Would you mind giving me the correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can add hyperlink using CSS, But you may use the jQuery.

```js
 $('.hlink').each(function() {
      var link = $(this).html();
      $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="#"></a>');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="txt"></td>
        <td class="hlink">Link</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```